# Pass cookie to browser via Intent

Tags: java, android

I have saved a cookie in android. Now I want to pass it into my browser intent. Look at my current code:

```
Intent browser = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
                            Uri.parse("http://mypage.php/memberpagethatrequireacookie.php"));
//putExtra cannot take these arguments -> browser.putExtra("org.apache.http.cookie.Cookie", cookie);
startActivity(browser);
```

I want it to store temporarily in my browser so my member page loads successfully. 
My cookie are successfully created from the HTTP request and I assign it to a `List<Cookie> cookie;`
Tell me if I should provide some more code.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Browser has no documented `Intent` extras, let alone one that would allow you to inject a cookie. And, of course, the user might be using a different browser.

You are welcome to use `WebView` in your application, and you can use the `CookieManager` to inject your cookie into the `WebView`'s environment.

Comment: So it is impossible to do it with the usual browser? Then, the WebView option is the way to go.

Comment: @Julian Assange: I am not aware that it is possible with "the usual browser". And some devices will replace that browser. And some users will replace that browser. The odds of all of them having agreed upon an undocumented protocol to accept cookies via `Intent` extras are fairly low.

Comment: Okey thank you. Another question appeared, but I will take that in another question. It is about the Cookie injection itself, that doesnt work.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the answer that uses android.proveder.Browser:

I have a Map object that I stored the header information I want to pass. Then the following:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
if(mExtraHeader!=null){
 for(String key: mExtraHeader.keySet()){
  bundle.putString(key, mExtraHeader.get(key));
 }
}
i.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_HEADERS, bundle);
startActivity(i);
```

Like the other guy mentioned, this would only work with the default browser and other browsers wouldn't have Browser.EXTRA_HEADERS I suppose. Resource: http://gitorious.org/rowboat/packages-apps-browser/blobs/a563d09392905140893d7a017dd63721577e1953/src/com/android/browser/BrowserActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

The above code is working fine to set headers (thanks for it), but I wasn't able to set cookies that way. What I suspect is that if the web browser already has cookies stored for the target URL, it will overwrite cookies created using EXTRA_HEADERS.

Comment: "Set-Cookie" is an HTTP answer header. We are talking here about the HTTP request "Cookie" header.

Comment: The "Cookie" header then... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

Comment: This indeed confirms what I said about "Requests" and "Response" HTTP header. A "Cookie" HTTP header can be sent in a request. A "Set-Cookie" header can be received in a response. As this question is related to sending a request by setting manually a cookie, we are talking about the "Cookie" header, not the "Set-Cookie" header, that wouldn't make sense in a request.