# Android How can automate login FB using jsoup

Tags: jsoup

I have two EditText(id,password) and one button(login).
When I click button I want to login FaceBook and open site.
But I can't watch already logged in site.

This is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText id;
    EditText password;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        id = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        Button logIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        logIn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Login();
            }
        });

    }

    public void Login (){
        System.out.println("id:" + id.getText().toString());
        System.out.println("password:" + password.getText().toString());


        try {
               Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1")
                            .data("email", id.getText().toString())
                            .data("pass", password.getText().toString())                            
                            .method(Method.POST)
                            .timeout(60000)//1 min
                            .execute();

                    Map<String, String> loginCookies = res.cookies();

                    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.facebook.com")
                        .cookies(loginCookies)
                        .get();

                    System.out.println(doc.text().toString());

           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
    }   
}
```

Comment: You are opening a FB session by login with JSoup. But this is useless if you do not transmit the returned cookies to the Intent (so FB think it's a new unauthenticated session). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717236/pass-cookie-to-browser-via-intent

Answer (score 0):

Scraping Facebook pages is against their [Terms of Service](https://www.facebook.com/ads/manage/customaudiences/tos.php) and a good way to get banned.  However, completely unnecessary since they provide an excellent [API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/).

Comment: Can you please cite the relevant part of the  article from the Terms of Service stating this point?